# How can I make an object solid in walk navigation mode?

Tags: objects, physics, navigation

I am "working" on a building project and what I want to do is to make **walls** (objects) **solid** so when I am in **walk navigation mode** not be able to **walk through** them. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: i do not believe that this is possible because the walk navigation is just a navigation inside blender without "intelligence". But this could be possible with camera movement and object constraints e.g.

Comment: Hm, interesting!!! Can I have more details please? An existing article or video tutorial? Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: And something else... How the walk navigation "understands" the gravity and stops on the floor? Shouldn't there be something similar for the walls?

Comment: it does not stop on the "floor". It walks in that direction, in which you are looking. Yeah, the "jump" is the only feature the amazing Blender team did implement there.

Comment: But if you hit "Tab" in walk navigation it gets gravity and stops where it finds an object below of it!!! Else it falls continuously until you hit "Esc".

Comment: oh ok. Didn't know that ;) learning every day here ;)

Comment: my idea which i had in mind was using limit location (outside) constraint. But...the problem with this constraint is that it calculates the distance between the (i think) pivot point (or whatever it is called) and the camera. So if the wall is just a bit longer this would make no sense because you could go through the wall, but if you increase the distance, you would stop long before the wall. Yeah, then you could build a wall from cubes with an array modifier and add constraints to all this little cubes building a wall, but i don't know whether you really want that... ;)

Comment: new idea....you could use physics + rigid bodies. I think your walls are rigid bodies anyway, right? So you create a rigid body, parent your camera to it, make that rigid body passive and animated...should work. i try that out

Comment: Hm... A lot of new information lol!!! I have to try things...